# How can I create Folder like Structure with n Key Value Pairs?

Tags: taxonomy-terms

I'm new to Drupal.

I'm trying to build the following structure

```
--Root
  --Cars
    --Luxury Car Campaigns (my "Folder")
      -Bentley CampaignInformation (1-n Key Value Pairs of different Types)
      -Lamgorgini CampaignInformation (1-n Key Value Pairs of different Types)
    --Japanese Car Campaigns (my "Folder")
      -Toyota Yaris CampaignInformation (1-n Key Value Pairs of different Types)
      -Corolla Verso CampaignInformation (1-n Key Value Pairs of different Types)
```

Note: A "Folder" is marked with a double-"--" and a key-value-list is marked with a single "-" (we call it internaly "Project"; but it is basically a named collection of key-value attributes/fields).

Every field can be of any type (Double, Data, Text and so on).

Every folder may contain unlimited subfolders or "Projects". (Must not be enforced by "Constraint")

Now the tricky Part (or not?):
Users can create Folders at any time. Users can create "Projects" in any Folder. Users can add any type of key-value pair to any Project.

Please give me a hint. Can this be done with Drupal? Do i have to dive into writing custom Modules?

I know a lot of Questions. Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is the usage of this datastructure?

Comment: @BetaRide The usage is, without going too much into detail, that the customer should be able to create and book campaigns with our software. Some customers might want to book campaigns for all Luxury-Cars, some others just for Bentleys. All information to this campaigns is entered by the customer... After that, the whole affected structure is exported to xml. To make a long story short: Its a customer requirement to organize his Projects this way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I get you right, this structure is a property of a campain. I'd create a hierarchical vocabulary and use it as a field in a custom content type create for the campains.

Comment: I'll accept this answer as i think as a beginner i should try taxonomies first. It seems to be a very core concept of drupal. I've tried out a little bit and it seems to work the way i want it.

Now I'm wondering if nesting of Vocabularies is possible...
I know i can nest "Terms"
Does this make sense at all? I think this is for another Question... 

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If its just hierarchial text/numbers/whatever content you want under "folders" you could try the built-in Book module. And then re-theme its display to have "parent" pages appear as folders and child-pages be your value fields (or pages). The nice thing you get here is some pre-built templates for "folder" indexes at every depth of the folder-tree.

Also the built-in book module supports HTML export and is pluggable so you can write your own custom `book_export_xml()` function, see:
[book.pages.inc book_export($type, $nid)](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!book!book.pages.inc/function/book_export/7)

Be aware drupal (book) pages nest at most 8 levels deep I believe by default -- I think there are work-arounds for this in the DB to go deeper (perhaps unlimited).

Or, you allow each user to have their own Taxonomy in drupal and try to use like Field Collection to allow users to create many values under a single term in the vocabulary.

Taxonomy sounds like it might meet your needs -- but you would likely have to make custom code something to allow users to create X number of taxonomies only they can see and manipulate.

Just fyi -- there is always a "maximum" in any dataset you have hardware constraints (RAM and harddisk) and can only store so much and still be responsive for the enduser. So be realistic and set yourself a max value, say 999 values per Key ....

Drupal can probably do what you want but it will take a fair amount of research.